# ContentCatcher: Failed to notify a WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to open a webview inside my fragment. But I am getting the error
ContentCatcher: Failed to notify a WebView.

Below is the code for my onCreateView of my fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_payment_gateway, container, false);


    webView=(WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.paymentwebview);
    WebSettings webSettings= webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl("www.google.com/");
    return rootView;
}
```

FragmentLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/paymentwebview">

</WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the Logs are

```
07-13 17:59:48.410 14386-14386/com.clubtro.dev D/EgretLoader:   
EgretLoader(Context context)
07-13 17:59:48.411 14386-14386/com.clubtro.dev D/EgretLoader: The 
context is not activity
07-13 17:59:48.423 14386-14386/com.clubtro.dev W/ContentCatcher: 
Failed to notify a WebView
```

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution? I have the same warning

Answer (score 0):

**This is just a warning you can ignore it**.

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bugtracker, container, false);
    mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");

    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    return v;
}
```

Comment: This didn't helped me.

Comment: please check I have updated my answer this is how I am using it inside fragment